# Nonplanar equilateral lattice "pentagons"

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

It is well-known that no two-dimensional point lattice contains a regular pentagon. (See for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticePolygon.html) The same is true for lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$, simply because any such polygon would lie in a two-dimensional sublattice. If we relax the requirement that the pentagon lie in a plane, we can easily find a closed path of 5 equal length sides: for example, in $\mathbb{R}^5$ with the integer lattice, we can use the path $$(1,0,0,0,0)\to(0,1,0,0,0)\to(0,0,1,0,0)\to(0,0,0,1,0)\to(0,0,0,0,1).$$ (These are the vertices of the standard 4-simplex.) The same construction, of course, works to find a nonplanar equilateral lattice "$n$-gon" for any $n$, as the vertices of the standard $n+1$-simplex in the integer lattice. We can improve this to a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ by restricting to the plane $x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$. My question is if this is the best we can do, dimension-wise. So is it possible, for example, to find a nonplanar equilateral lattice pentagon in some lattice in $\mathbb{R}^3$? What can be said about the minimal dimension of lattice containing a nonplanar equilateral lattice $n$-gon?

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619435/posssible-pentagons-in-3d answer your question?

Comment: Planar cases do exist in three-dimensional space (see below), but not (or at least, not obviously) parallel to a two-dimensional coordinate plane. See below.

Answer (score 1):

We can identify equilateral pentagons in the *hexagonal* two-dimensional lattice, which can be described in the complex plane as $a+b\omega$ where $a,b$ are integers and $\omega=(1\pm i\sqrt3)/2$ is a non-real cube root of unity. In terms of this reprentation pentagon $ABCDE$ defined below has sides of length $7$:

$A=0,B=-7\omega,C=7,D=15+3\omega,E=8+3\omega.$

We may also interpret the hexagonal lattice as a cross-section of the cubic lattice $\mathbb{Z}^3$. The vectors from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,-1,0)$ and from $(0,0,0)$ to $(-1,0,1)$ both have length $\sqrt2$ and are directed $120°$ from each other, so we may replace $a+b\omega$ from the complex plane with

$a(1,-1,0)+b(-1,0,1)=(a-b,-a,b)$

in the three-dimensional lattice. Thereby the above pentahon $ABCDE$ with sides of lemgth $7$ becomes the planar pentagon $A'B'C'D'E'$ in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with sides $7\sqrt2$:

$A'=(0,0,0),B'=(7,0,-7),C'=(7,-7,0),D'=(12,-15,3),E'=(5,-8,3).$