# Equilateral and almost equiangular polygons in 3D

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

This is a generalization of the following question.

[Posssible pentagons in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619435/posssible-pentagons-in-3d)

Let $P$ be an $n$-gon in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume that $P$ has equal side lengths and $(n-1)$ interior angles are $\theta$, where we assume that $0<\theta<\pi$.
Then what is the possible value for $\theta$?

We can formulate the question as follows. Let $v_1, \dots,v_n \in \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the sides of $P$.
We set  $v_{i,j}:=\left<v_i,v_j\right>$, where $\left<,\right>$ denotes the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Assume that the following three equations hold.

\begin{align}
&v_1+v_2+\dots+v_n=0. \qquad (1)\\
&v_{i,i}=1 \quad \text{for $1 \leq i \leq n$}.\qquad (2)\\
&v_{i,i+1}=-\cos \theta \quad \text{for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$}. \qquad (3)
\end{align}
Here the minus sign to $\cos \theta$ is due to the fact that $\theta$ is an interior angle.

I would like to know for what $\theta$, the equations (1), (2) and (3) have a solution.
I guess that the answer is:

(i) If $n$ is odd, then $\frac{\pi}{n} \leq \theta \leq \frac{n-2}{n} \pi$.

(ii) If $n$ is even, then $0<\theta\leq \frac{n-2}{n}\pi$.

Note that $\frac{n-2}{n} \pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{n}$ are the regular polygon and a star polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, respectively. 
Is my answer true?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, just a remark about your estimate, which looks too restrictive when $n$ is even.

In fact, if we start with a planar regular $n$-gon (with $n$ even and inner angle 
$\alpha={n-2\over n}$) we can construct a 3D-polygon with $n$ equal side lengths and $n$ equal interior angles $\theta$, simply by raising all even vertices of the original $n$-gon of some amount $a$ with respect to their plane, and lowering all odd vertices by $a$. A simple calculation shows that
$$
\cos\theta={\cos\alpha+4a^2\over1+4a^2}.
$$
The right hand side expression spans all values between $\cos\alpha$ and $1$:
it follows that we can obtain any $\theta\in(0,\alpha]$ by choosing an appropriate value for $a$. But in your question you allow for one angle to be different, so there should be room for some more allowed values of $\theta$.